# Firebase security rule works in Simulator but not in Angular code

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

I have a barebones chat app working on Angular and Firebase, but am having trouble working with the security rules.

I've created the following rule as a test and **it works in the simulator** but won't work with the object I'm passing Firebase from Angular.

```
{
"rules": {

  "chat": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":"newData.child('text').val() === 'test'"
  }
 }
}
```

My angular code looks as follows. $rootScope.userDing is just an object that holds the user's information upon auth.

```
var app = angular.module("fpl-chat", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://glaring-torch-9680.firebaseIO.com/chat");

  $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

  $scope.addMessage = function() {
    if ($rootScope.userDing) {
        $scope.toAdd = {
            text: $scope.newMessageText,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            user: $rootScope.userDing.name,
            imgSrc: $rootScope.userDing.imgSrc,
            uid: $rootScope.userDing.uid
        }
    } else {
        $scope.user = 'Guest';
        $scope.imgSrc = 'assets/img/guest.png';
        $scope.uid = 'guestUID';
    }
    $scope.messages.$add($scope.toAdd);
    $scope.newMessageText = '';
  };

});
```

If `$scope.newMessageText` is `'test'` then it still doesn't allow the write operation.

The error I get is:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /chat/-K-YU0reCudVPu_8t74s failed: permission_denied
```

Where am I going wrong or does anyone have any debugging tips?

Comment: I've tried a few other rules and things but it doesn't seem to work with any.

Comment: Security rules and authentication are completely different topics. Can you post your entire ruleset?

Comment: Check the changed code :)

Comment: How about the rest of the controller/service code? Specifically, wherever `$scope.messages` is being set.

Comment: No way to reproduce your problem with so little code. There's also a lot you can do to narrow the scope here: start by replacing those variables with strings containing the values, rule out possibilities until you've verified the point at which the problem goes away. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay I added the controller's code. I also tried just making the object very simple just with text: 'test' and it still won't work. $scope.messages.$add({text:'test'})

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"rules": {

  "chat": {   
    ".read": true,

    "$chatMsg": {
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.child('text').val() === 'test'"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I had to add another layer of ruling for the individual chat messages, very simple really.

See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html (Part 3: Make Your Rules Dynamic)